# Show that if $P(x)$ is an polynomial with an uneven degree then there exists a $x_0\in \mathbb{R}: P(x_0) < 0$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I have eddited the Question, I hope the Statement is now true.

I want to show that every such polynomial has a zeropoint, If I can prove the Statement above, I can use the indermediate value Theorem.

What I have worked out so far is that

$P(x)$, can be rewritten in the form of:

$P(x)= a_0x^{2k+1}+a_1x^{i_1}+a_2x^{i_2}+...a_jx^{i_j}+C,j\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and $2k+1>i_1>…>i_j$

$= (a_0x^{2k+1-i_j}+a_1x^{i_1-i_j}+...+a_j)x^{i_j}+C$

$= ((a_0x^{2k+1-i_j-(i_{j-1}-i_j)}+...a_{j-1})x^{i_{j-1}-i_j}+a_j)x^{i_j}+C$

$=((a_0x^{2k+1-i_{j-1}}+...a_{j-1})x^{i_{j-1}-i_j}+a_j)x^{i_j}+C$

$...$

$=(…(a_0x^{2k+1-i_1}+a_1)x^{i_2-i_1}+a_2)…)x^{i_{j-1}-i_j}+a_j)x^{i_j}+C$

How can I continue, do you have any suggestions?

I had the idea to pick

$\max\limits_{0 \leq s \leq j}|a_s|$ as my $x$

I somehow think that $P(x)$ would either be positive or negative dependant whether I pick $+x$ or $-x$. If that goes in the right direction I need somebody to tell me how to proceed.

Comment: You want to use this to prove the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Your statement is imprecise. The polynomial $P(x)=x$ has odd degree $1$ but does not have a positive or a negative zero.

Comment: The claim in your title is not true. What are you actually trying to prove?

Comment: No what I want to show is that every polynomial of uneven Degree has a zeropoint. If I can show that for every such polynomial there exists a positive and a negative value i.e. $\exists_{z,z'\in\mathbb{R}}:P(z)>0,P(z')<0$ I can make use of the intemediate value Theorem to say that $\exists x$ in the intervall $[z,z']$ or  $([z',z])$: $P(x)=0$. Therefor I assume without loss of generality that $P(x)>0,\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and try to invoke a contradiction by constructing a $x$ with negative value.

Comment: look at the limits. (if $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$) it should give you the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume WLOG that $a_{2n+1}\gt0$. 
We have $p(x)=a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}+\dots+a_0$.  But, as you take the limit as $x$ approaches $\pm\infty$, the leading term dominates.  That is, $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}p(x)=lim_{x\to\pm\infty}x^{2n+1}(a_{2n+1}+\frac{a_{2n}}{x}+\frac{a_{2n-1}}{x^2} +\dots+\frac{a_0}{x^{2n+1}})=\lim_{n\to\pm\infty}a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}=\pm\infty$.

Comment: Why can you Claim that so easily don't you have to give an explicit $a$ such that $\forall_{r\in\mathbb{R}}\exists_{a\in\mathbb{R}}\forall_{x\in\mathbb{R}}:x\in(a,+\infty)\Rightarrow p(x)>r$

Comment: But no worries I could solve and understand the Problem now.

Comment: Well that's fairly easy to do;  given that the expression in parentheses approaches $1$.  That is, take $x$ such that  both $x^{2n+1}\gt\frac r{a_{2n+1}}$ and the expression in parentheses is sufficiently close to $1$.  There are some details to consider,  but it clearly works out.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had it but I still don't understand it why does the expression in the parentheses approach 1? Take for example $\frac{a_0}{x^{2n+1}}$ it is true if I take a big $x$ then the term goes as close to 0 as I want but I if I multiply this value by$ x^{2n+1}$ then I have$ a_0 $again which does not have to be $1$

Comment: Yeah, typo on my part.  The expression in parentheses approaches $a_{2n+1}$.  And you have given the reason why:  the other terms all go to zero.

Comment: But the idea of multiplying Limits is only valid if $x^{2n+1}$ would converge which it does not

Comment: It doesn't.   But the second sequence converges,  hence is bounded.  From this you can prove the limit of the product is unbounded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88153/discussion-between-chris-custer-and-rm777).

Comment: Btw, we're assuming $a_{2n+1}\neq0$.  That about clinches it.  Only if we got $0\cdot \infty $ would we run into a problem.